# How can I convert an absolute file path to one CSS can use?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, filepath, glob

I'm trying to display a randomly-chosen background image on a WordPress site. My strategy is to inline the `style` attribute of the `<html>` element, like so:

```
<html style="background:#e8e6da url(<?php
$bg_imgs = glob(get_template_directory().'/backgrounds/*.jpg');
shuffle($bg_imgs);
echo $bg_imgs[0]; ?>) left top fixed">
```

On my local server, this outputs

```
<html style="background:#e8e6da url(C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite/wp-content/themes/my_theme/backgrounds/paper2.jpg) left top fixed">
```

...which the browser doesn't like because it's asking to fetch a local resource. Even if this wouldn't be a problem once the site is live, I only need a relative path to the image file.

So I was about to mess with using `substr()` to chop off the unneeded part of the path, but I can't be sure, depending on where the site is deployed, what `get_template_directory()` will return. I don't want to hard-code anything that might vary.

What's the best strategy for returning a random image path relative to the site URL? I'm happy to ditch the above if there's something better.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I would just wait until this site is live and hard code the URL.

Comment: In this case, I need to review the site on a local server with the client, and it has to work. Also, this is part of a theme and so should be portable by the client.

Comment: In that case, maybe you could: a) hard code it once to show the client. and then b) set a form to insert a file path (which is stored in a variable, passed to the css, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try getting the document root and chopping it off the beginning of your full path:

```
$docRoot_len = strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$bg_imgs = glob(get_template_directory().'/backgrounds/*.jpg');
shuffle($bg_imgs);
echo substr($bg_imgs[0], $docRoot_len);
```

I know this is not foolproof - it's just an idea.

Comment: Based on this idea, I did this: `<html style="background:#e8e6da url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/<?php
$bg_imgs = get_template_directory();
$root_path_length = strlen($bg_imgs);
$bg_imgs = glob($bg_imgs.'/backgrounds/*.jpg');
shuffle($bg_imgs);
echo substr($bg_imgs[0],$root_path_length); ?>) left top fixed">` which seems to work! I don't see why it wouldn't work when the site is live... do you?

Comment: It should work on any site: you're effectively taking the absolute path and taking out the base part that is the docroot - leaving you with the path of the document.  The only thing to be careful about is that you keep the starting "/" in the remaining path.

Comment: Yep, hard-coded it, as you can see. Sweet, man, this helped me a lot. I never considered counting the characters returned by `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`get_bloginfo('template_url')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) instead, or probably [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

Comment: That's the first thing I did and `glob()` needs a full filepath, I guess: it returns nothing.

Comment: Well, you ARE mixing filesystem paths with URL paths. That's a no-no. You'll have to massage the paths that glob returns to turn them into something that's valid for urls.

Comment: Right. Hence the question. What's the best strategy to do this?

Comment: I'd build an array that contains both the filesystem AND url paths for those images. Given the amount of url rewriting and whatnot that can take place, there's probably no easy to way to convert between the two versions after the fact.